# Flask URL Route: Route Several URLs to the same function

Tags: python, url-routing, flask

I am working with Flask 0.9.

Now I want to route three urls to the same function:

```
/item/<int:appitemid>
/item/<int:appitemid>/ 
/item/<int:appitemid>/<anything can be here>
```

The `<anything can be here>` part will never be used in the function.

I have to copy the same function twice to achieve this goal:

```
@app.route('/item/<int:appitemid>/')
def show_item(appitemid):

@app.route('/item/<int:appitemid>/<path:anythingcanbehere>')
def show_item(appitemid, anythingcanbehere):
```

Will there be a better solution?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Why not just use a parameter that can potentially be empty, with a default value of `None`?

```
@app.route('/item/<int:appitemid>/')
@app.route('/item/<int:appitemid>/<path:anythingcanbehere>')
def show_item(appitemid, anythingcanbehere=None):
```

Comment: very easy, intuitive, effective solution.

Comment: How about for this one mate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539950/how-to-have-a-single-search-api-using-path-parameters-no-form-used

Comment: I wish I can add a dozen of upvotes at once

Answer (score 18):

Yes - you use the following construct:

```
@app.route('/item/<int:appitemid>/<path:path>')
@app.route('/item/<int:appitemid>', defaults={'path': ''})
```