# how to have a single search API using path parameters (No form used)

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have been using this view for searching a `word` as:

`db` refers mongo connection (just for ref)

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/words-<word>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wordsearch(word):
    collection_name=word[0].lower()+'_collection'
    words=db[collection_name]
    data=words.find({'word':word})
    return render_template('wordsearch.html',data=data)
```

In `index.html` template I have been doing this to match this above url as:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#submit').on('click', function() {
              var wordvalue = $("#word").val();  //getting word from element ID 
              window.location.href ="/"+"words-"+wordvalue; //match the URL in view
              })
         });
    </script>
```

Does this can be done in more dynamic way ?, I mean this only works for `word` and not for other selections,or combination of selections as below:

The search input looks as:

```
word length: ()
word type  : ()
word       : ()
         submit
```

Now the API I have does match only if I send word , but how can I write a single API such that it should match all the possible combinations like word `length + word type`, `word + word type` (queries I would define on own)

What I have tried is :

```
@app.route('/<n>-letter-words', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/words-<word>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wordsearch(word=None,n=None):
    if word:
        collection_name=word[0].lower()+'_collection'
        words=db[collection_name]
        data=words.find({'word':word})
        return render_template('wordsearch.html',data=data)

    data = 'you are searching with' + n + 'words'
    return render_template('lettersearch.html', data=data)
```

and in templates the `script`as:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#submit').on('click', function() {
              var lettervalue = $("#wordlength").val();
              var wordvalue = $("#word").val();
              if (lettervalue==''){
                    window.location.href ="/"+"words-"+wordvalue;
               }
               else{
                window.location.href ="/"+lettervalue+"-letter-words";
               }
              })
         });
    </script>
```

But confused if there are combination's like, 
     `6-letter-words-of-verbs` verb is a `word type` here

Also how to match the same URL for these combination's from template as i was doing with JQuery used in `script` above?

Is this the correct way? , I guess writing all possible routes in views and match it from template with the conditions in Jquery is a bad idea ,

any help/guiding links are appreciated ,TIA

Comment: This approach may be… ill-advised.  Is `/foo+bar` and `/bar+foo` the same resource?  A: no.  Will they produce the same effective results?  Depends on the underlying search engine in use, but URI should be _unique_.

Is `/search?foo+bar` and `/search?bar+foo` the same resource?  A: yes.  Both are the "search" resource, just provided different "query strings".  It being _called_ a «query» string should be a strong hint as to the intended purpose.

Edited to add: note, no form need be involved in the construction of a query string.  Forms just make it easier, but restrict you to `key=value`.

Comment: Ah, and a very brief follow-up; a desire to avoid (rather than make use of / exploit) standard browser behaviours is often not a good sign in terms of _groking_ how the "web" (beyond just HTTP) is supposed to work.  [Never forget what the actual MVC separation is, here.](http://f.cl.ly/items/0P0g0B3U2y2H0y3E1E38/Screen+Shot+2017-07-30+at+05.15.37.png)

Comment: @amcgregor absolutely makes sense, so it always recommended to go with based on `/search?bar+foo` so that i can avoid any `jquery` , is that right or did I understood it wrong?

Comment: @amcgregor sorry, I could not get the second point at all

Comment: [You](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) [can](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery) [always](https://hackernoon.com/you-truly-dont-need-jquery-5f2132b32dd1) [avoid](https://css-tricks.com/now-ever-might-not-need-jquery/) [jQuery](http://vanilla-js.com).  While I dislike ES5 quite heavily, ES6 is, well, beautiful.  And multiple orders of magnitude faster.  The point is to follow the intent of the [definition of a URI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), and to not dismiss automatic functionality provided by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment-suggested recommendation to not [ignore the behavior of the client browser](http://f.cl.ly/items/0P0g0B3U2y2H0y3E1E38/Screen+Shot+2017-07-30+at+05.15.37.png), and to follow the [intent of the definition of a URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (where `/foo+bar` and `/bar+foo` must not represent the same resource), the following is all you *actually* require, and handles URI-encoding of the values automatically, where your original did not handle URI encoding at all, and requires no additional client-side JavaScript of any kind:

```
<form action="/search"><input name="q"></form>
```

This is essentially how Google's (or DuckDuckGo's, or Yahoo!'s, or…) search form operates.  Default method is GET (use a query string), input field given the abbreviated "field name" `q` (short for `query`).  Using a tiny bit of JS one can bypass the form-encoding and apply the query directly *as* the "[query string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)" — but remember to URI/URL-encode the value/query/search terms before combining!  (And that doing this may bypass any "form data" collection performed by your backing web framework, e.g. you'll need to pull out `request.query_string` yourself.)

Comment: so , in view how can i handle empty inputs sent from form? for eg: I have 4 fields , `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and I hit search just giving `a` and now how I should handle this in view?

Comment: for only `a` i have one condition , similarly for all and also i have conditions for their combinations like (if `a` and `b`) are searched do something........how to handle all these in view method under route?

Comment: @Codenewbie Within your Flask application's endpoint / view, access [`request.query_string`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.query_string) to access the query string itself.  Regardless of whatever combinations are passed in; it's all just a string.  (99% of the time UTF-8, so you'll want to `.decode('utf-8')` that.)

Comment: @Codenewbie If using a standard HTML form submission (with a "field name" the submitted string is being "assigned" to) you'll need to access [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args) instead, e.g. `request.args['q']` if your `<input name="q"…>`.  See the [Quickstart tutorial, here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#the-request-object).

Comment: when I did something as, submitting only `lettersearch` field i got in url (http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?lettersearch=6&wordsearch=) and `400 bad request`

Comment: @Codenewbie This is becoming a situation better handled by chat, which I can not provide. Please update your initial question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io), replicating how you are constructing that form.  Because that looks all kinds of strange, and impossible to debug without seeing the form producing that.

Comment: I solved it sir, the thing I am doing mistake is you mentioned query `strings` but from form i am sending integer , silly that i have been querying with `string 6` not `6` , sorry for all your time on this .

Answer (score 0):

In flask you can get the arguments from the request itself.

```py
    from flask import request

    @app.route('/endpoint')
    def myfn():
        val1 = request.args.get('arg1')
        val2 = request.args.get('arg2')
```

So you can do something like this in front-end:

```html
<form action='/word-search' method='GET'>
    <input type='text' name='wordlen' />
    <input type='text' name='wordtype' />
    <input type='text' name='word' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

And at server end,

```py
@app.route('/words-search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wordsearch(word):
    wordlen = request.args.get('wordlen')
    wordtype = request.args.get('wordtype')
    word = request.args.get('word')
    ...
```

Comment: so, on submit i don' t have to do anything from template?

Comment: No, you can submit the form

Comment: here i am not using any form , because i am just showing fields and a search button , on search/submit i want to map to exact URL in the view, so the script i have used in template

Comment: submitting a form on '/' is the easier method. If you want to submit it using js code, still you can use the form method. If you somehow can't use form methods, you can load the URL as '?arg1=val1&arg2=val2'

Comment: I have updated my question , may be you understand it now

Comment: I have updated my answer. It's actually very simple; not that confusing

Comment: The thing is I want to show in the URL not just `words-search` , but ` words-<word>`

Comment: in the example, URL will be shown as `/word-search?wordlen=10&wordtype=text&word=helloworld`. That's not okay with you? coz that's a standard

Comment: yes I understand but instead i want to show like , 6-letter-words-......

Comment: I didn't completely understand what you are trying to do. As far I understood, you are trying to route varieties of URLs to the same function. You can route varieties of URL's as you did, but that is NOT the correct way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205134/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-npk).