# Set route to array flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```py
@app.route(["/api/user/creationdate", "/api/user/createdat", "/api/user/createddate"])
def cd(user):
  ... code here
```

The above code doesnt return any errors and doesnt work for me. Is there a way to assign multiple routes to one function?

## Edit (how to do this)

```py
@app.route("/route1")
@app.route("/route2")
@app.route("/route3")
def cd():
  ... code here
```

doing this will have all of the routes above trigger the function `cd()`

Comment: Yes, try the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14023664/15368978). Basically, you want to define a decorator for each url you want for that route.

Comment: i had no idea that i needed multiple app route decorators, thats pretty odd. thank you

Comment: got it, just edited with the answer for anyone else that needs to know, thanks patrick