# I'm not sure why my edit endpoint is not working

Tags: flask

Whenever I'm creating a Flask code lines to my project, I ain't able to successful create the EDIT for my CRUD. Please, can anyone help me to troubleshoot and have it ready to work?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my codes.

---

INDEX.HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<section>
    <div class="para-container">
        <div class="parabox">
            <h1>Here is where you can find the joy</h1>
            <p>Discovering the pure joy of riding on two wheels: Your ultimate motorcycle destination</p>
            <a href="{{url_for('register')}}">Subscribe for our next event</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="hero-banner">
    <div class="hero-banner__title" aria-hidden="true">Are you ready?</div>
    <img class="hero-banner__image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/motorbike.jpg')}}" />
    <h1 class="hero-banner__title hero-banner__stroked-title">Are you ready?</h1>
</div>

<section>
    <div id="call-box" class="para-container second">
        <h1>Who will be there?</h1>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img img-second" src="static/images/img-meeting-1.jpg" alt="Latest rider">
            <div class="cards">
                <h3>Érica</h3>
                <p>Ireland</p>
                <p>Honda CBR 1000</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img img-second" src="static/images/img-meeting-2.jpg" alt="Latest rider">
            <div class="cards">
                <h3>Fábio</h3>
                <p>Brazil</p>
                <p>Kawasaki 1200</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img img-second" src="static/images/img-meeting-3.jpg" alt="Latest rider">
            <div class="cards">
                <h3>Alan</h3>
                <p>Brazil</p>
                <p>Yamaha FZR 1000</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img img-second" src="static/images/img-meeting-4.jpg" alt="Latest rider">
            <div class="cards">
                <h3>Adam</h3>
                <p>Poland</p>
                <p>Honda Crosstourer 1200</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="db-table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <h1 class="db-title">Subscribers</h1>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Guest Name</th>
                    <th>Event</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for registration in registrations %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ registration.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ registration.guest_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ registration.event }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ url_for('edit', index=index) }}">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{ url_for('delete', index=index) }}">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

---

EDIT.HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="reg-container">
    <h1>Edit Registration</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('edit', index=index) }}" method="post">
        <label for="name">Rider name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ registration.name }}" required>

        <label for="guest_name">Guest name (if applicable):</label>
        <input type="text" id="guest_name" name="guest_name" value="{{ registration.guest_name }}">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="{{ registration.email }}" required>

        <label for="event">Event:</label>
        <select id="event" name="event" required>
            <option value="party" {% if registration.event == 'party' %}selected{% endif %}>Meetings</option>
            <option value="conference" {% if registration.event == 'conference' %}selected{% endif %}>Conference</option>
            <option value="workshop" {% if registration.event == 'workshop' %}selected{% endif %}>Workshop Sales</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

RUN.PY

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define the path to the JSON file
json_file_path = "data/members.json"

# Check if the JSON file exists, and load data if it does
if os.path.exists(json_file_path):
    with open(json_file_path, "r") as json_data:
        registrations = json.load(json_data)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", registrations=registrations, enumerate=enumerate)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


@app.route("/contact")
def contact():
    return render_template("contact.html")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get form data
        name = request.form.get("name")
        guest_name = request.form.get("guest_name")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        event = request.form.get("event")

        # Create a registration dictionary
        registration = {"name": name, "guest_name": guest_name,
                        "email": email, "event": event}

        # Add registration to the list
        registrations.append(registration)

        # Save registrations to the JSON file
        with open(json_file_path, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(registrations, json_file, indent=4)

        # Redirect to the index page with the updated registrations
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    return render_template("register.html")

@app.route("/edit/<int:index>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit(index):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get form data
        name = request.form.get("name")
        guest_name = request.form.get("guest_name")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        event = request.form.get("event")

        # Update the registration in the list
        registrations[index]["name"] = name
        registrations[index]["guest_name"] = guest_name
        registrations[index]["email"] = email
        registrations[index]["event"] = event

        # Save updated registrations to the JSON file
        with open(json_file_path, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(registrations, json_file, indent=4)

        # Redirect to the index page with the updated registrations
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    # Render the edit form with the existing data
    return render_template("edit.html", registration=registrations[index])

@app.route("/delete/<int:index>")
def delete(index):
    del registrations[index]
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        host=os.environ.get("IP", "0.0.0.0"),
        port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", "5000")),
        debug=True)
```

I tried to change the url_for method to achieve the edit page, but nothing worked.

And I keep getting the error below:

*werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'edit'. Did you forget to specify values ['index']?*

Comment: is the delete working? I think you have to remove "index" from  "def edit(index):"

Answer (score 1):

your url expect int:index parameter but I believe you are not passing it to the home route ("/") so the index is become none to prevent you can define [another route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023701/21275789) without index or you can pass index to the home route to use it to link other pages